# Completing words with hyphens with company

Tags: company-mode

I am using company buffer completion.  But cannot get to match ligatures with hyphen in them.  What can I do to complete parts containing hyphens?

Suppose I have the following text

```
;; This buffer is for-text that is not saved, and for Lisp-evaluation.
;; To create a file, visit it with C-x C-f and enter text in its buffer.
```

But entering `for` does not show `for-text`, and `li` does not show `Lisp-evaluation`.

This is the function that I am using

```
(defun company-sequencer ()
  "Place 'company feature in a ready operational state."

    (setq company-minimum-prefix-length 2)

    ;; Expand words with Dynamic Abbreviation
    (setq company-backends '(company-dabbrev company-dabbrev-code))

    ;; Explore text in current buffer, then in all open buffers
    (setq company-dabbrev-other-buffers 'all)
    (setq company-dabbrev-ignore-case 'keep-prefix)

    (setq company-dabbrev-code-other-buffers 'all)
    (setq company-dabbrev-code-ignore-case t)
    (setq company-dabbrev-code-everywhere t)) )
```

Comment: Show a step-by-step recipe, starting from `emacs -Q` to reproduce your problem. Say what you see at each step, and what you expected to see instead.